# Can't figure out what the Syntax error is

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Okay so I have this running through a select case

in case 0 it runs:

```
Sql = "INSERT INTO Devices (" &
           "[Asset Number], [Service Tag], Manufacturer, ModelName, Location, Room, Cart, [Purchase Date], Department, [Device Type]" &
           ") VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"

                'Query Parameteres.
                Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Sql, dbConn)
                    'Have to guess at column types/lengths here. Use actual types/lengths from your DB
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Asset Number", OleDbType.Integer).Value = AssetNum
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Service Tag", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ServTag
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Manufacturer", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255).Value = Manu
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Model", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50).Value = Model
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Location", OleDbType.VarWChar, 30).Value = Location
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Room", OleDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = Room
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cart", OleDbType.VarChar, 2).Value = Cart
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Purchase Date", OleDbType.Date).Value = PurchDate
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Department", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50).Value = Department
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Device Type", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = DeviceType
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
```

In Case 1 it runs:

```
 Sql = "INSERT INTO MVNTA (" &
    "[Serial Number], [Ethernet Mac], [Wlan Mac], Imei, ESN, HEX, DEC, Phone, [NTA Tag], Manufacturer, Model)" &
    ")VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"

            'Query Parameteres.
            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Sql, dbConn)
                'Have to guess at column types/lengths here. Use actual types/lengths from your DB

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Serial Number", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = ServTag
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ethernet Mac", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Ether
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@WLan Mac", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = WLan
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMEI", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = IMEI
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ESN", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = ESN
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Hex", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = HEX
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DEC", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = DEC
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255).Value = Phone
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@NTA Tag", OleDbType.Integer).Value = AssetNum
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Manufacturer", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255).Value = Manu2
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Model", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50).Value = Model2
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
```

Case 1 has a syntax error, but when I compare them, I can't find the issue.
I have compared the lengths in the database, and they're correct. Though I don't completely understand varchar vs varwchar I don't think the issue is in that.  Case 0 is working for inserting into the Devices table.

I also took the statement directly into the database, fixed some minor issues with it, and it ran. Upon putting it back into my application code the Syntax error returned.

Comment: Looks like an extra parenthesis here - `Model)" &`

Comment: `DEC` is a reserved word; `HEX` could be, it is not in the list I am looking at but since it is a VB function, I'd escape it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HEX` and `DEC` are [problem words](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) under OleDb.  Enclose those names in square brackets.

And remove the extra parenthesis which [Mark spotted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437210/cant-figure-out-what-the-syntax-error-is/31437300#comment50844325_31437210).

```
Sql = "INSERT INTO MVNTA (" &
    "[Serial Number], [Ethernet Mac], [Wlan Mac], Imei, ESN, [HEX], [DEC], Phone, [NTA Tag], Manufacturer, Model)" &
    " VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you. Didn't even consider the idea that I was using reserved words.